# ReactPixiでの動画ボリュームの変更の仕方

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pixi.js

`@pixi/react`を用いて動画の再生を試みています。
動画の再生と停止自体は下記のコードで動作しましたが、ボリューム変更の方法がわかりません。

```
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  ...
  if(...){ //when click "close"
     videoRef.current.destroy(true); // stop video
  }
...
  return(
...
            <Sprite
              image={videourl}
              width={width}
              height={height}
              x={0}
              y={0}
              ref={videoRef}
            />
    )
```

下記:stackoverflowでも質問中
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78230276/how-to-change-the-volume-of-video-on-reactpixi